# Bash script for searching for a string in a XML file and rename the file with the string

Tags: bash, search

I have a lot of report files in a folder called XXXXX.xml and i need to search for a string in each one of this file to rename the file with a particular string, for instance:

I have this file called 28022018.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<SampleResults XMLCreationDateTime="2018-02-23T10:28:45" XMLVersion="7">
<SampleResult AreReproTestOutliersIgnored="No" ReproTestResult="NotUsed" ReproTestType="None" Instrument="PXC01" MethodName="Fe-91" RecalculationDateTime="2018-02-22T12:26:16" BackupStatus="Original" Origin="Measured" CorrType="None" Type="Unknown" OperatorName="" Name="18-1325">
<SampleIDs>
    <SampleID Type="Text" KeepLastValue="False" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="False" IsSampleName="True">
        <IDName>Sampe Name</IDName>
        <IDValue>18-1325</IDValue>
        </SampleID>
    <SampleID Type="GradeName" KeepLastValue="True" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsSampleName="False">
        <IDName>Grade ID</IDName>
        <IDValue>1.8161 58CrV4</IDValue>
    </SampleID>
    <SampleID Type="Text" KeepLastValue="False" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="False" IsSampleName="False">
        <IDName>New</IDName>
        <IDValue>Cliente</IDValue>
    </SampleID>
</SampleIDs>
</SampleResult>
</SampleResults>
```

I need to create a script that save the string in the properties tag NAME written on 3 line (name ="18-1325"), and use it to rename the file from 28022018.xml to 18-1325.xml.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really quick and dirty script to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in ./*.xml; do
    echo Checking $filename
    aux1=`grep -oE ' Name=\"(.*)\"' < $filename | cut -f 2 -d '"'`
    cp $filename $aux1.xml
done

echo Done!
```

Basically what it does:

- Iterates over all `*.xml` files in the current dir
- Searches for the line containing " Name="
- Cuts the target text and takes the value of the XML field
- Copies the file to a new file

I made a couple of copies of your XML and tested it (name should have different values or you will end up with a single file:

```
$ cat sample1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleResults XMLCreationDateTime="2018-02-23T10:28:45" XMLVersion="7">
<SampleResult AreReproTestOutliersIgnored="No" ReproTestResult="NotUsed" ReproTestType="None" Instrument="PXC01" MethodName="Fe-91" RecalculationDateTime="2018-02-22T12:26:16" BackupStatus="Original" Origin="Measured" CorrType="None" Type="Unknown" OperatorName="" Name="18-1325">
<SampleIDs>
    <SampleID Type="Text" KeepLastValue="False" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="False" IsSampleName="True">
            <IDName>Sampe Name</IDName>
            <IDValue>18-1325</IDValue>
            </SampleID>
    <SampleID Type="GradeName" KeepLastValue="True" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsSampleName="False">
            <IDName>Grade ID</IDName>
            <IDValue>1.8161 58CrV4</IDValue>
    </SampleID>
    <SampleID Type="Text" KeepLastValue="False" MustExist="False" IsReadOnly="False" IsSampleName="False">
            <IDName>New</IDName>
            <IDValue>Cliente</IDValue>
    </SampleID>
</SampleIDs>

$ ./script.sh
Checking ./sample1.xml
Checking ./sample2.xml
Done!

$ ls

18-1325.xml
18-1326.xml
sample1.xml
sample2.xml
```

*UPDATE*: Thanks to @Arusekk comment! Using `grep -oE` makes the script even easier!

Comment: You can use `grep -o` (`--only-matching`) to avoid the `cut -f 17` uncertainty.

Comment: Thanks @Arusekk! I updated the solution accordingly!

Comment: `grep -oE '...' <"$filename"` is more efficient than `cat "$filename" | grep ...` (and less buggy than the version of that without the quotes, which will fail with filenames with spaces).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, it will work in case the number of parameters in line 3 gets changed.

Taking code inspiration from [Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3046834/victor) and modifying it.

You can still refine it to make it more beautiful, take special care of spaces around **"SampleResult "** and **" Name="**  :

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in ./*.xml; do
    echo "Checking ${filename}"
    new_file_name=$(cat ${filename} | grep 'SampleResult ' | grep 'Name' | awk -F' Name=' '{print $2}' | tr -d '">')
    cp ${filename} ${new_file_name}
done
```

Comment: `cat file | grep pattern ` is inefficient compared to just `grep pattern file`.

Comment: Even better, `awk '/SampleResult/ && /Name/ { ... }' <file` would avoid *both* `grep`s, and the `cat` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse XML with `bash`, `grep`, `sed` or `awk`. Use a dedicated tool instead as for example `xmllint`, which is part of the packages `xml2-utils` on Debian.

```
name=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//SampleResult/@Name)' input.xml)
if [ "$name" ]; then
  mv input.xml "$name".xml
fi
```

BTW: your XML example is broken. The closing tags for `SampleResult` and `SampleResults` are missing.

Comment: Do the dedicated XML tools handle broken XML like this one?

Comment: @Victor, that's assuming it really *is* broken, vs the OP copy-and-pasting only a subset of the file to try to show the only parts they thought we'd need. The latter is much more likely, as the former would require *creating* the file with non-XML-aware tools in the first place, and folks have generally been trained out of that via the scorn of their seniors/peers/users/code-reviewers over the last decade-and-a-half.

Comment: OK. I was just thinking that a valid XML is an extra precondition that must be met, on top of the fact that you must be allowed to install such tools (that´s not always the case). That´s the reason why I prefer standard tools, but I guess this solution might be good as well.

Comment: @Victor, the thing about "standard tools" built for string manipulation that aren't XML-aware is that they don't understand XML at all. They don't know to ignore comments, they can't recognize escaped sections that need to be treated as data instead of syntax (`CDATA` sections), they don't recognize aliases and DTD macros, they don't grok namespaces (and understand that an `xmlns=` entry changes the type of every attribute deeper in the tree)... and if you use them to *edit* XML, then they can *and do* create malformed XML that nobody else can parse on a regular basis.

Comment: All things that you mentioned are not normally done within bash scripts, you have plenty of languages and tools for that, used in a more serious fashion. The question at hand was in need of a quick fix rather the complex processing you mentioned (just renaming a file, remember? No namespaces, comments, etc). IMO

Answer (score 0):

As another approach that also uses proper XML-aware tooling (in this case, [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)):

```
for f in *.xml; do
  read -r new_name < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//SampleResult[@Name]' -v ./@Name -n <"$f")
  [[ $f ]] && [[ $f != "${new_name}.xml" ]] && mv -- "$f" "$new_name"
done
```

Note:

- Using `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or another XML-aware tool is essential for correct operation: Otherwise, your code won't know to ignore any `SampleResult` that's inside a comment or a CDATA section, for example.
- Using `read -r new_name < <(...)` instead of `new_name=$(...)` captures only the first line of output, so if a file has multiple names, we skip all but the first.
- Using the quotes and `--` in `mv -- "$old_name" "$new_name"` ensures that the names are parsed *as names*, even if it starts with a dash, contains spaces or globs, etc. See [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), entry #10.